# How to read BMP file location of image used for picture symbol in LYR file?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology, layer-file

I have a number of *.lyr files which are pointing to various .bmp files which are used as marker symbols in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1

I was wondering if there is a way to extract the file paths of the *.bmp files each *.lyr file uses for its picture symbol.

Is it possible to do this using Python?

Comment: Why not just add them to a map and follow through the Symbology tab of the Layer Properties where that should be revealed?

Comment: I have many layers files, each pointing to many .bmp files, so this would be quite a tedious process.  I was hoping there was an automatic way to extract these paths.

Comment: I think ArcObjects will be your only option to do this programmatically.

Comment: as far as I can tell the picture itself is imported into the stdole.IPictureDisp for IPictureMakerSymbol/IPictureFillSymbol and not the reference to the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of @Michael Miles-Stimson concluding that the ...

> picture itself is imported into the stdole.IPictureDisp for
>   IPictureMakerSymbol/IPictureFillSymbol and not the reference to the
>   bitmap

I have concluded that this cannot be done using ArcPy (nor in its underlying ArcObjects).